# wordpress api return an error: Call to a member function get_page_permastruct()

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to send a request to the WordPress API, but it returns this error:

> Call to a member function get_page_permastruct().

Plugins WooCommerce, WooCommerce Print Invoices/Packing Lists and Yoast SEO, when there are activated, caused the problem.

Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the basic-auth plugin then it could be responsible for the error. I had this issue and I had to add some code to `basic-auth.php`.

After the username and password i added a condition to check if `init` has been run yet.

```
$username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
// Add the following:
if ( ! did_action( 'init' ) ) {
  return $user;
}
```